# How to lock a property and a channel in xfconf

Tags: configuration, xfce

I find instructions at https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/start hard to follow. There is a chapter about Kiosk mode. It tells

> Locking a channel or property is as simple as creating a configuration file and setting either (and only either) the “locked” or “unlocked” attribute on  or  elements that should be restricted. This configuration file should be placed in a system location that is read by the daemon (see “File locations” above).

What is the syntax of such a configuration file? Where are the "File locations"? Should the file be created, when Xfconf is not running? Can you terminate Xfconf during a Xfce session, or should you log out before creating the file?

Comment: HTH https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/tree/docs/spec/perchannel-xml.txt

Comment: @AndreLDM yes, it helped me to enable lock. I had to log out and log in to Xfce session to apply changes in the files.